# Django - таймаут кэша считается после последнего обращения или после его установки?

Tags: python, django, кэширование

```
from django.core.cache import caches, DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS

cache = caches[DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS]
cache.set(cache_key, data, timeout)
```

Вопрос такой - я устанавливаю значению в кэше таймаут, предположим, 300 секунд. Кэш сбросится через 300 секунд после момента его установки, или через 300 секунд после последнего обращение к нему?

```
data = cache.get(cache_key)
```

Comment: Я предполагаю, что после момента обращения

Comment: Это зависит от используемого хранилища, а не от джанги. Известные мне кэширующие БД (memcached, redis) сбрасывают спустя 300 секунд после именно установки

Comment: если redis сбрасывает кэш спустя заданное время именно после установки, то мой вопрос можно считать закрытым.